# react-admin ArrayInput

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin, aor-embedded-array

ReferenceInput not working with ArrayInput.
How to do something like the following?

```
    <ArrayInput source="comments">
      <SimpleFormIterator>
        <ReferenceInput source="comments" reference="user">
          <AutocompleteInput optionText="username" />
        </ReferenceInput>
      </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `ReferenceArrayInput` ?

Comment: ReferenceArrayInput solves a different use case - e.g. when you want to choose a list of values (usually foreign keys) from another REST endpoint.
ArrayInput is for inputting an array of objects which are not yet existing in the backend. 
Anyway, (fyi) the above code snippet already works in latest version of react-admin. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue and it has been fixed in `2.1.5`. See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2079 for the pull request and https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v2.1.5 for the release.